# Azure DevOps pipelines for project and deployment specific variables

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am wanting opinion on the following. Have a javascript qna bot that I have in Azure DevOps. I have an azure pipeline created that deploys to an Azure environment. This works well. However, this is a common use bot that can be used in multiple scenarios. Write Once, Use Many. So I want to variabl-ize the process for multiple environments (DEV vs PROD) and instances (PROD1, PROD2, PROD3...)

**1st Case**: Within the project, there is a .env file with name-value pairs stored. I need to have distinct values for multiple environments and instances. One option could be to have a distinct file per environment+instance. So

.env.DEV, .env.PROD1, .env.PROD2, .env.PROD3, etc.

And then as part of the build process that zips the files, rename only one of the .env files by dropping the suffix based on the case. Can delete the other .env files prior to zipping. Is this a good way to do it OR is there a more standardized process that I should use?

**2nd Case**: As part of the deployment, I want to variabl-ize the azure-pipeline.yml file so that the target webapp, resource group, subscription, etc are dynamic (different for DEV, PROD1, PROD2, ...). I can create multiple yaml files and link it to separate pipelines. Is this the way? Or am I creating one pipeline and somehow toggling these values for 'n' different cases?

I can hack something. But I wanted to make sure I was using the right approach before starting.

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st Case**:

> Is this a good way to do it OR is there a more standardized process that I should use?

I suggest you can use [replace token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to achieve your needs which could be more convenient. Here is my sample:

1.*.env file:

```
name1:#{value1}#
name2:#{value2}#
name3:#{value3}#
```

2.Create variables and set values when running the pipeline:

[image]

3.Replace token task:

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  inputs:
    targetFiles: '**/*.env'
    encoding: 'auto'
    writeBOM: true
    actionOnMissing: 'warn'
    keepToken: true
    tokenPrefix: '#{'
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
    useLegacyPattern: false
    enableTelemetry: false
```

4.Result of *.env file:

```
name1:a
name2:b
name3:c
```

**2nd Case**:

> I can create multiple yaml files and link it to separate pipelines. Is
> this the way? Or am I creating one pipeline and somehow toggling these
> values for 'n' different cases?

I suggest you can use [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#parameters) and select values when running pipelines. For example:

```
parameters:
  - name: subscription
    type: string
    default: test1
    values:
      - test1
      - test2
  - name: WebAppName
    type: string
    default: test1
    values:
      - test1
      - test2
  - name: ResourceGroupName
    type: string
    default: test1
    values:
      - test1
      - test2

steps:

- task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
    Action: 'Stop Azure App Service'
    WebAppName: ${{ parameters.WebAppName }}
    SpecifySlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.ResourceGroupName }}
```

You can choose the resource group name and subscription name when running pipelins:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Walter Qian! That worked perfect for 1st Case. Now I have "N" Build Pipelines operating off a single azure-pipelines.yaml file with variables defined in each Pipeline definition

However on 2nd Case: I can set it the way you suggested. However, I wouldn't want to make the parameter selection each time manually. How can I make the build-specific (for each target) AzureAppServiceManage@0 values be applied automatically each time?

Comment: Looks like I might be able to use something called "dynamic variable groups". I will get started on that. But if I am taking the wrong path, don't hesitate to caution me.. :)

Comment: I did 2nd Case using Build variables. Ofcourse, I need to repeat these in every PROD pipeline. But it seems to work. Any reason I should prefer Parameters or Dynamic Variable Groups?

Comment: You can change variable type to secret in variable groups and it is more secure. You can use a variable group to store values that you want to make available across multiple pipelines. Parameters are used for the current pipeline.

Comment: Thanks again Walter Qian.